# Why split method does not support $,* etc delimiter to split string

Tags: java, regex

```
import java.util.StringTokenizer;
class MySplit
{
  public static void main(String S[])
  {
    String settings = "12312$12121";
    StringTokenizer splitedArray = new StringTokenizer(settings,"$");

    String splitedArray1[] = settings.split("$");
        System.out.println(splitedArray1[0]);

    while(splitedArray.hasMoreElements())
        System.out.println(splitedArray.nextToken().toString());            
  }
}
```

In above example if i am splitting string using `$`, then it is not working fine and if i am splitting with other symbol then it is working fine.

Why it is, if it support only regex expression then why it is working fine for `:`, `,`, `;` etc symbols.

Comment: you have to escape the special characters by '\$'

Comment: because `$` is a special character in regex you have to escape it by `settings.split("\\$");`

Comment: I'm not sure : and ; are special characters in regular expressions either. Refer to the section titled "Summary of regular-expression constructs" [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)

Comment: how we can check that how many symbols are getting treated as special symbol. Is somewhere any list where we can get how many symbols are used as special symbol.
What is the purpose of these special symbols in Regx.

Comment: @VinaySharma: `\.[]{}()*+-?^$|` Also refer this: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/literals.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`$` has a special meaning in regex, and since [`String#split`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-) takes a *regex* as an argument, the `$` is not interpreted as the string `"$"`, but as the special [meta character](http://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html) `$`. One sexy solution is:

```
settings.split(Pattern.quote("$"))
```

[`Pattern#quote`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#quote-java.lang.String-):

> Returns a literal pattern String for the specified String.

... The other solution would be escaping `$`, by adding `\\`:

```
settings.split("\\$")
```

---

**Important note**: It's extremely important to check that you actually got element(s) in the resulted array.

When you do `splitedArray1[0]`, you could get [`ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.html) if there's no `$` symbol. I would add:

```
if (splitedArray1.length == 0) {
    // return or do whatever you want 
    // except accessing the array
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you take a look at the Java docs you could see that the `split` method take a regex as parameter, so you have to write a regular expression not a simple character.

In regex `$` has a specific meaning, so you have to escape it this way:

```
settings.split("\\$");
```

Answer (score 2):

Dollar symbol $ is a special character in Java regex. You have to escape it so as to get it working like this:

```
settings.split("\\$");
```

From the [String.split](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) docs:

> Splits this string around matches of the given regular expression.
>
> This method works as if by invoking the two-argument split method with
>   the given expression and a limit argument of zero. Trailing empty
>   strings are therefore not included in the resulting array.

**On a side note:**

Have a look at the **[Pattern class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)** which will give you an idea as to which all characters you need to escape.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the [`split(String str)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-) method expects `str` to be a valid regular expression. The characters you have mentioned are special characters in regular expression syntax and thus perform a special operation.

To make the regular expression engine take them literally, you would need to escape them like so:

```
.split("\\$")
```

Thus given this:

```
String str = "This is 1st string.$This is the second string";
        for(String string : str.split("\\$"))
            System.out.println(string);
```

You end up with this:

```
This is 1st string.
This is the second strin
```

Answer (score 1):

Because $ is a special character used in Regular Expressions which indicate the beginning of an expression.

You should escape it using the escape sequence \$ and in case of Java it should be \$

Hope that helps. 
Cheers